# Pending Intent Causing mainactivity to reload, why is that?

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I'm trying to write a service that will check every midnight for new data from the server and will download it.

But when i start the app the mainActivity screen reloads after few seconds. 
I'v checed it and it happens because of this service,
Why is this happening?

Her are the files:

**MainActivity:** i'v created an AlarmManager object to set pendingIntent:

```
//Set alarm
    /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60;

    /* Set the alarm to start at 10:30 AM */
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

**AlarmReciever:**

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Data newData = null;
    public SharedPreferences settings;
    ConnectivityManager cm = null;
    NetworkInfo netInfo = null;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        newData = new Data(context);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        newData.cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        newData.netInfo = newData.cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        newData.settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
//        System.out.print("-----------------" + newData.netInfo);
        newData.checkOnline();
    }
}
```

**Data.java:**

```
    public void checkOnline(){
    if (isOnline()){
        System.out.print("**************** YES Internet");
        firstAsyncTask task = new firstAsyncTask(this);
        try {
            Object dobj = task.execute("par1", "par 2", "par 3").get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else{
        System.out.print("**************** NO Internet");
    }
}
```

The data.java file is to big to post in here, but it seems that the "checkOnline" method in in causing the app to reload the MainActivity page, should i send the service differently?

Thanx for reading & answering.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have written this line  by mistake

`pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);`

It should be like this

`pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);`

Because you are using BroadcastReciever.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, i fixed it and its still happening

Comment: According to your code there is no clue why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Causes the following line network access?

```
Object dobj = task.execute("par1", "par 2", "par 3").get();
```

If so then the system might kill your process (ether for networking on main thread or for event loop timeout aka. ANR). And eventually restart it again if its a service.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Activity` you do this:

```
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

This causes the `BroadcastReceiver` to be triggered immediately, since you have specified `System.currentTimeMillis()` as the time to trigger the first time.

You probably mean to use `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` as the first time to trigger the alarm. But even if you change it to that, **it will still trigger immediately** because you've set the time in your calendar to 00:00 of the **current day**, which has already passed! You need to either use `calendar.getTimeInMillis() + interval` (which would be 00:00 of the **following day**, or you can add 1 day to your calendar before using `calendar.getTimeInMillis()`.