# not able to set alarm for more than 20 seconds

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcast, repeatingalarm

I had created alarm manager which invoke after 2 minutes which I want. But currently, i'm not able to set it more than 20 seconds. if I set for 20 seconds it returns output but if I set it for more than 20 I'm not able to set. I want to set it for 2 minutes. kindly help me.
 I had added alarm fire code

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) ContextGetter.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intnt = new Intent(ContextGetter.getContext(), AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intnt.setAction("com.demo.alarmEvent");

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ContextGetter.getContext(), 0, intnt, 0);

        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+ 30*1000, pending);
```

kindly help me
 i want it set it only once.

I also tried with this one.

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                                                                Intent intnt = new Intent(EnterSysNumber.getInstance(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                                                                intnt.setAction("com.demo.Enter_number");
                                                                PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intnt, 0);
                                                                manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 120000, pending);
```

Comment: " i'm not able to set." Meaning?

Comment: @alldani i want  to set it for 2 minute but when i set it for 2 minutes it not working right now i set it for 30 seconds testing purpose.

Comment: What language is that? JS?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37546550/alarm-manager-with-2-pending-intents-only-1-works And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526160/pending-intent-causing-mainactivity-to-reload-why-is-that Also try: http://pythontutor.com

Comment: no man it java android

Comment: This is great to see what doesn't happen as you planned it would: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: try to use setExact mathod of Alarm Manager

Comment: @TabishHussain i also tried with setExact() but not work. i'm not able to see any output on logcat

Comment: @alldani i'm not able to set my code inside pythontutor.com

Comment: What happens? Make sure you select the right language before running.

Comment: I'm not able to set Android as language inside Pythontutor.vom

Comment: It works perfectly when I set timeout for 20 seconds but not working when I set larger then 20

Comment: @alldani i checked your answer they use setRepeating() and i want to set only once.

Comment: Not my answer but, though I don't know Java (python) I thought it might help.

Comment: @alldani thanks for answer but i didn't get any solution.

Comment: Try this to get more attention to your question: [ask] | [mcve] | [help]

Comment: ok i'll try it. and send you feedback

Answer (score 0):

In Android N you'll run into Doze mode. Doze is a deep sleep mode to save battery power. It will prevent your service to preserve battery power.

AlarmManager and using `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` when in low-power idle modes this duration may be significantly longer, such as 15 minutes.. But this is NOT suggested for any Play Store app, you will kill your user's battery.

Comment: But it work well when i set for 20 seconds but when i set it for more than 20 it not work. please help me i need it  as fast as i can.

Comment: @ravi_koriya Use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` for more info check (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: My min API is 18 and target API is 23

Comment: Then why don't you use `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` (Timer.https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)  _But this is not working 24/7_

Comment: I have 4 different broadcast receiver in my project so, is there any problem with it ? there all are for different usage.

Comment: And i have 1 progressbar which visible for 2 minute if between that time no output receive then it stop and invisible.

Comment: If you want to show a `ProgressBar ` until process has complete then you can show a transparent dialog with progress bar within your activity. When the task has completed or time out you can dismiss that dialog.

Comment: but it visible when app is running but when user close app. it not visible also if operation not complete within 2 minute then automatically close.

Comment: Yes, you can send a Event to your activity to show the dialog which user cannot cancellable. And all the activities in your application need to extend with 'BaseActivity'. All events and ui implementation of dialog should be implement in 'BaseActivity'. For parse events you can use `EventBus` library. Which you can register your activities and unregister your activity.

Comment: can u tell me how can i use event but for 2 minute time

Comment: First you need to resister your activity in `onCreate` method: `EventBus.getDefault().register(ActivityName.this);`, then while your start service sent Event to your Activity `EventBus.getDefault().post(new ExampleObject());`. In your activity `public void onEvent(ExampleObject event) {}` this listen all events send via `ExampleObject` from `EventBus`